# the site packages folder in python is marked red along with subfolders

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, site-packages

the site packages in pycharm are appearing red in color and i cannot import anything from the sub folders.I have tried going to settings-->project structure-->add,,and nothing works.I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling pycharm and still the same.There is no "mark directory" option in the folder on right clicking.PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 0):

You can't just take any sort of folder it has to be a python package
So it must look like this :
[image: correct]